# Finding a reduction formula

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Find a reduction formula for 
$$I_n= \int x \cos^n{x} dx.$$
I have used integration by parts as
$$u=x, dv=\cos^n{x}dx,$$
then
$$I_n=x\int\cos^n{x}dx-\int\left(\int\cos^n{x}\right)dx,$$
where
$$I^*_n=\int\cos^n{x}dx$$ 
is the well-known reduction formula, then
$$I_n=xI^*_n-\int I^*_n dx.$$
Is this correct, or is there another answer?

Comment: You're missing a dx in the third latex line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n \geqslant 2$,
\begin{align*}
I_n &= \int x \cos^n x \,\mathrm{d}x = \int x \cos^{n - 1} x\,\mathrm{d}(\sin x)\\
& = x \sin x \cos^{n - 1} x - \int \sin x \,\mathrm{d}(x \cos^{n - 1} x)\\
&= x \sin x \cos^{n - 1} x - \left(\int \sin x \cos^{n - 1} x\,\mathrm{d}x + \int x \sin x \cdot (n - 1) \cos^{n - 2} x (-\sin x) \,\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
&= x \sin x \cos^{n - 1} x + \int \cos^{n - 1} x\,\mathrm{d}(\cos x) + (n - 1) \int x \sin^2 x \cos^{n - 2} x \,\mathrm{d}x\\
&= x \sin x \cos^{n - 1} x + \frac{1}{n} \cos^n x + (n - 1) \int x (1 - \cos^2 x) \cos^{n - 2} x \,\mathrm{d}x\\
&= x \sin x \cos^{n - 1} x + \frac{1}{n} \cos^n x + (n - 1) \int x \cos^{n - 2} x \,\mathrm{d}x - (n - 1) \int x \cos^n x \,\mathrm{d}x\\
&= x \sin x \cos^{n - 1} x + \frac{1}{n} \cos^n x + (n - 1)I_{n - 2} - (n - 1)I_n,
\end{align*}
thus$$
I_n = \frac{1}{n} x \sin x \cos^{n - 1} x + \frac{1}{n^2} \cos^n x + \frac{n - 1}{n} I_{n - 2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much @Alex Franko